# Regex to return 1 if string pattern matched, otherwise return 0

Tags: regex

I have a text string like this "mysqld is alive", which can be different.
If text string contains "is alive" I need a regex to return 1, otherwise if not matched then return 0.
Is it possible to do this with a regex ?
The app's regex supports use of capture groups \1, \2 ...

It's not a language, it's an application, which has fields for regex to manipulate item's text string. The app uses pcre library.

The app supports multiple regex steps.

Comment: what have you tried ? Which language ?

Comment: It's not a language, it's an application, which has fields for regex to manipulate item's text string. The app uses pcre library.

Comment: How about [this](https://regex101.com/r/gx0bvD/1)

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work for me. I tried this one: "(mysqld is alive|stopped)(?=.*:\1=(\d))", but it returns an empty string. Okay, I found another workaround to avoid regex for this. The question can be closed.